# association Array push as the first index

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
array (
  0 => 'val_1',
  1 => 'val_2',
  2 => 'val_3',
  3 => 'val_4',
  ...
);
```

i want to add `'str'=>'val_n'`as first index of array, i've tried array_unshift, but it looks it doen't desing for this situation.

output array should be like:

```
   array(
   'str'=>'val_n',
    0=>'val_1',
    1=>'val_2',
    2=>'val_3',
    ...
    );
```

how can I do it?

Comment: _looks it doen't desing for this situation_ can you show your code and the given result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `array_merge`

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 'val_1',
  1 => 'val_2',
  2 => 'val_3',
  3 => 'val_4',
);

$toAdd = array('str' => 'val_n' );

$arr = array_merge( $toAdd , $arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [str] => val_n
    [0] => val_1
    [1] => val_2
    [2] => val_3
    [3] => val_4
)
```

Doc: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`+` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) to merge two arrays:

```
$array = array (
  'val_1',
  'val_2',
  'val_3',
  'val_4',
);

$array = ['str' => 'val_n'] + $array ;

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [str] => val_n
    [0] => val_1
    [1] => val_2
    [2] => val_3
    [3] => val_4
)
```